# RESTful web service with GenericType

Tags: java, web-services, rest

here is the first part of my code :

```
@Path("compute/{x}")
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN) // "text/plain"
public List<Double> compute(@PathParam("x") Double x) {
    List<Double> list = new Vector<Double>();
    list.add(Math.log(x));
    list.add(Math.exp(x));
    return list;
}
```

I am learning/building a RESTful web service. The client exploiting that RESTful web service is doing like this.

```
javax.ws.rs.client.Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();

WebTarget uri_basique = client
        .target("http://localhost:8080/Rest_ws/rest");

WebTarget targeted_resource = uri_basique.path("simple/compute/{x}")
        .resolveTemplate("x", 5);

Builder builder = targeted_resource.request(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN);
List<Double> compute = builder.get(new GenericType<List<Double>>(){});

System.out.println("log (5) = " + compute.get(0));
System.out.println("exp (5) = " + compute.get(1));
```

It is supposed to work. But when I execute I get:

```
javax.ws.rs.InternalServerErrorException: HTTP 500 Internal Server Error
    ...
    at ws_rs.Client.test3(Client.java:26)
```

The problematic line is the line :

```
List<Double> compute = builder.get(new GenericType<List<Double>>(){});
```

If someone can provide any explanation/solution to me.

Comment: What is appearing in your server side logs?

Comment: I am checking. wait a minute.

Comment: `HTTP 500 Internal Server Error` means your server is down.

Comment: nothing else than what I posted

Comment: HTTP 500 Internal Server Error means your server is down ? how can you explain that in the current situation ? See my code.

Comment: the code is fine. the problem was how you wrapped it with Tomcat.

Comment: The line with **GenericType** poses a problem. I don't know why. It should be working from what I've learned.

Comment: `List<Double> list = new ArrayList<Double>()` `vector` was from `java.util.AbstractList`

Comment: the code is fine. the problem was how you wrapped it with Tomcat. I forgot to mention it. I am using Glassfish with Jersey 2.0.

Comment: With **ArrayList**, the same error is showing. Not any change.

Comment: The problem is not in your client code - it is in your server code. The server is returning an HTTP 500 error in response to your request. What happens if you issue the request from a browser ( navigate to http://localhost:8080/Rest_ws/rest/simple/compute/5 ) ?

Comment: **What happens if... browser **. The error shows in the browser. http status 500 - Internal Server Error

Comment: so that proves it's not your client code .... is there anything else that is displayed in the browser that is useful? Are you sure nothing is being logged in the server logs?

Comment: DaveH, you are inevitably on the right path. I see  **MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/xml, type=class java.util.ArrayList, genericType=java.util.ArrayList<java.lang.Double>**

Comment: DaveH, you are inevitably on the right path. I see **MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/xml, type=class java.util.ArrayList, genericType=java.util.ArrayList<java.lang.Double>**

Answer (score 2):

HTTP 500 Internal Server Error means that there is some error while calling the rest api. It seems that the web service is not able to translate list as "text/plain" and hence it is throwing error. Jersey does not provide  `MessageBodyReader/Writer` to translate java.util.List into "text/plain". You have to provide a custom `MessageBodyReader/Writer` for this.